# How to use the GRASS GIS v.net.timetable tool in QGIS?

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-processing

The GRASS GIS v.net.timetable tool needs the following input information:
(a) a vector layer with the network
(b) a vector layer of points (from - to)
(c) and the timetable.

The [GRASS manual on the subject](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.net.timetable.html) is very brief (developed for GRASS GIS users) and it is not so easy to deduce as the timetable format should be in QGIS.

Also, I'm not finding where to indicate the timetable path.

Has anyone used this tool and got results?